# Screwturn Wiki Search Latency

Tags: search, wiki, screwturn

Does anyone know of ways to optimize the screwturn search functionality?
We've been using it for internal documentation, and I'm the tech expert on it, but I have not had the opportunity to analyze it much.  After inputting a lot of information into it, we've noticed that text searches take a noticeable delay; on the order of up to 10 seconds in some cases.  I'm pasting a screengrab of the search index status here.  We have a good 30 different namespaces, which I suspect is more than we really need, but the decision was made to use them for organizational purposes, and I couldn't think of a reason why not.  Is it possible the high number of namespaces impacts the search time?

When doing tests on the search, the only resource spike I could find was a big CPU usage spike on the webserver.

[image: Search Index Status screengrab]

Comment: What version of Screwturn wiki are you using?  Is this using the standard Search box "{SEARCHBOX}" or the more advanced Search Engine page?  If the Search Engine page, what option are you specifying.  It may simply be a missing index on the database that would help.

Comment: The wiki version is 3.0.5.600.
I've noticed this in both the search box and the search engine page.  If I restrict the search to a particular namespace, I noticed it does improve the result time.

I thought about the index on the database, but I thought that would impact the processing on the database server, but the CPU spike I was noticing was on the web server (a different machine from the database server).

Comment: If you profile the SQL for a single search from your original question, you will likely notice that the web app is very chatty with the database.  Having a larger number of namespaces to search will have an impact on search performance due to the way the search is performed (by namespace, from what I have seen, seems very inefficient).  After reviewing the code a bit, I can see where you might see a spike on the web server.  The best bet would be to refactor the search function to work better with a larger # of namespaces.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it right, as it's the best run-down we have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you profile the SQL for a single search from your original question, you will likely notice that the web app is very chatty with the database. Having a larger number of namespaces to search will have an impact on search performance due to the way the search is performed (by namespace, from what I have seen, seems very inefficient). After reviewing the code a bit, I can see where you might see a spike on the web server. The best bet would be to refactor the search function to work better with a larger # of namespaces.